# Return json into ajax from Action Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, fullcalendar

Am currently working on fullCalendar (jQuery plugin) and now stuck with silly issue but I couldn't overcome it .

Trying populate event details from database on Calendar page load . Here is my code ,

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2016-03-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            eventSources: [
                     getEvents()
                     ] 
        });

        function getEvents(){
            alert("Inside get Events");

            $.ajax({
                url : "/FullCal/eventDetails.do",
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(data){
                    alert(data)
                }
            });
        }
```

Am using Struts framework and here is my action mappings,

```
<action path="/eventDetails" type="com.struts.action.CalendarInviteAction" >
            <forward name="success" path="/Calendar.jsp" />
        </action>
```

And my action class has the event details data in JSON format. My question is how to write the json data into ajax response(In simpler words , how to return the json data to ajax call) . Here is my action class ***UPDATED***

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping , ActionForm form , HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response) throws  Exception{

        System.out.println("TEsting inside getEventDetails");

        ArrayList<EventForm> arr = new ArrayList<EventForm>();

        arr.add(new EventForm("HandOff Meeting" , new Date(), new Date(),"Meeting at HandOffBridge"));

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(arr);

        response.getWriter().write(jsonString);

        return null;
    }
```

jsonString contains eventDetails in JSON format , how to return this to ajax.

Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax call seems fine. Just need to display ajax response in proper way.

```
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url : "/FullCal/eventDetails.do",
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data){
      callback(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dataType : 'json'` is used by [jQuery Ajax][1] to specify a data type that is expected to return by the `success` callback function when the action and result is executed, and a response returned from the server.

> `dataType` (default: Intelligent Guess (`xml`, `json`, `script`, or `html`))
>
> Type: `String`
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).

The URL should correctly point to the action mapping. Assume it will be in the default namespace, otherwise you should modify URL and mapping to add the `namespace` attribute.

```jsp
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog ({
      autoOpen: true,
      height: 500,
      width: 750,
      modal: true,
      buttons : {
        "Search" : function() {
          $.ajax({
            url : '<s:url action="part" />',
            success : function(data) {
              //var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
              var obj = data;
              alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Kishnan . I have updated my action class code in the post . I want to return jsonString to ajax .Please take a look and help me out .

Comment: I have added new answer please try that syntax code., Thankyou

Comment: Thanks for your response . I want to return the string from Action class to ajax call . Based on my understanding , if i used data as you mentioned it just added to the ajax request . Please correct if am wrong

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is why return null?

```
return null;
```

Just return the json string:

```
return jsonString;
```

Comment: Since this is an ajax call, just return null so that struts does not take any further action.